# Generate google form from google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I did the following code.

```
    /**
 * Creates a Google Form de um arquivo do Google Sheet, publica o formulário e manda o link para o seu e-mail.
 */
function createAndSendForm() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var nomeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName();
  var nomePlanilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var form = FormApp.create('2020' + nomeSheet);
  // This represents ALL the data
  var inicio = 4; // pegar da planilha
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var qColunas = 6;
  var values = range.getValues();
  var nPerguntas = 14; // pegar da planilha

  for (var i = inicio; i < nPerguntas; i++) {
   var tituloPergunta = values[i][0]; // range.getValues()
   var item = form.addCheckboxItem();
   item.setTitle(tituloPergunta);
   Logger.log(tituloPergunta);

  for (var j = 1; j < values[i].length; j++) {
     var alternativa = values[i][j];
     Logger.log(alternativa);
     item.getChoices().push(item.createChoice(alternativa))
    }
    }
}
```

The code has an integration of capturing as questions in planning and putting them in a form, a question I want is a multiple alternative.
The data is in cells A4F14.
In column A are questions, B starts as alternatives and ends at F. All options are in the same quantity, that is 5 alternatives.
But my code is not creating the form, it asks a question, but it does not pose as alternatives.
can anybody help me?

Comment: It will help other users understand your intent, and so to help find your bug, if your code comments and variable names are all in one language. If you can, use English here to get more views. You could also try over on pt.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can do it with [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
 for (var i = inicio; i < nPerguntas; i++) {
    var tituloPergunta = values[i][0];
    var item = form.addCheckboxItem();
    item.setTitle(tituloPergunta);
    values[i].shift();
    item.setChoices(values[i].map(function (choice) {
      return item.createChoice(choice);
    }));
  }
```